# How to extract data from from tr element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I trying to extract data from every "<tr onclick=..." on webpage but without success.

Here is webpage
[image]

And this is my code with error on line 17

```
import time 
import pandas as pd 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.page_load_strategy = "none"
driver = Chrome(options=options) 
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
url = "C:/Users/Mirko/Desktop/test.htm" 
driver.get(url) 
time.sleep(5)

content = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id*='ContentPlaceHolder1_divPageContent'")
flights = content.find_elements(By.XPATH(".//tr[@onclick]"))

def extract_data(element): 
    antStatus = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antStatus'")
    antStatus = antStatus[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antFlight = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antFlight'")
    antFlight = antFlight[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antCS = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antCS'")
    antCS = antCS[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antCity = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antCity'")
    antCity = antCity[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antID = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antID'")
    antID = antID[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antSTD = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antSTD'")
    antSTD = antSTD[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antETD = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antETD'")
    antETD = antETD[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antATD = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antATD'")
    antATD = antATD[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antATT = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antATT'")
    antATT = antATT[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antBAY = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antBAY'")
    antBAY = antBAY[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antGATE = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antGATE'")
    antGATE = antGATE[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antTYPE = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antTYPE'")
    antTYPE = antTYPE[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antREG = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antREG'")
    antREG = antREG[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antSU1 = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antSU1'")
    antSU1 = antSU1[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antSU2 = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antSU2'")
    antSU2 = antSU2[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antRMK = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antRMK'")
    antRMK = antRMK[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antPOZ = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antPOZ'")
    antPOZ = antPOZ[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antBUS = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antBUS'")
    antBUS = antBUS[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antCheckin = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antCheckin'")
    antCheckin = antCheckin[0].get_attribute("textContent") 
    antDeicing = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='antDeicing'")
    antDeicing = antDeicing[0].get_attribute("textContent") 

    return { 
        "antStatus": antStatus, 
        "antFlight": antFlight, 
        "antCS": antCS, 
        "antCity": antCity, 
        "antID": antID,
        "antSTD": antSTD,
        "antETD": antETD,
        "antATD": antATD,
        "antATT": antATT,
        "antBAY": antBAY,
        "antGATE": antGATE,
        "antTYPE": antTYPE,
        "antREG": antREG,
        "antSU1": antSU1,
        "antSU2": antSU2,
        "antRMK": antRMK,
        "antPOZ": antPOZ,
        "antBUS": antBUS,
        "antCheckin": antCheckin,
        "antDeicing": antDeicing
    }

data = [] 
 
for flight in flights: 
    extracted_data = extract_data(flight) 
    data.append(extracted_data) 
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df.to_csv("ob.csv", index=False)
```

I try to scrape data from webpage in ob.csv file and add scraped data at the below last line. Additionaly I trying to add one more column at the right side with scraping time in format hh:mm:ss.

Any help ?

Comment: you probably want to axe that "."... try with just //tr[@onclick]  The "." is for current active node.

Comment: @pcalkins Same error     flights = content.find_elements(By.XPATH("//tr[@onclick]")) 
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: try/catch that "content = " call... doesn't seem like you are getting back a WebElement object.